# how to compile c program using php script in ubuntu

Tags: php, c++, gcc

I am developing an online testing system through which we can conduct online programming contests.
For the same i want to invoke the C compiler from the php script using the functions like `system()`, `shell_exec()`, `exec()` etc. But the function is not creating a.out file
when i wrote `g++ a.cpp -o a` using terminal it worked.

But this is not working

```c
system("g++ a.cpp -o a",$as); //a.cpp is inside www folder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP runs as a different user to yourself, and so probably doesn't have permission to execute the `g++` command.

To make the command accessible to PHP, try this:

```
sudo chmod o+x /usr/bin/g++
```

N.B. `/usr/bin/g++` can sometimes be a symbolic link to another executable in the same directory, and so changing its permissions won't do anything (symlinks are 777 by default). If the above command doesn't resolve the issue, can you add the output of this command to your question, which will show where it points to:

```
ls -al /usr/bin/g++
```

On my system, this outputs

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 2011-08-10 14:52 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.5
```

This means `g++` is essentially an alias of `g++-4.5`, so I would allow 'other' execute permissions on `g++-4.5` instead:

```
sudo chmod o+x /usr/bin/g++-4.5
```

Comment: my issue is still not resolved
output of command is "
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      7 Mar 14  2012 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 357312 Apr 16  2012 /usr/bin/g++-4.6"

Comment: In your case, run `sudo chmod o+x /usr/bin/g++-4.6`. I've added a more generic solution to my question.

Comment: i have tried that but it didnt work.
p.s i had run the above code using terminal
then refreshed the php file(index.php) and it didn't create a.out file
if i have to do some other way then please mention as i am a newbie.thanks

Comment: Try it with absolute paths, e.g. `system('g++ /var/www/a.cpp -o /tmp/a.out', $as);`. If that works, you can then go on to change the output location - but make sure 'other' has write access to the directory.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted give a reason so I can improve my answer?